# Configuration Error when formatting Python with Black in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pipenv, python-black

I can't setup black to format when saving in VSCode.

- I went through the steps in the black [docs](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/editors.html#visual-studio-code)
- Installed the VSCode plugins: [black formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.black-formatter) and [python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)
- Setup personal configuration (I also tried this same configuration in the project scope `.vscode/settings.json`):

```json
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": "explicit"
    }
  },
```

I am using [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to setup my environment `pipenv shell`, `pipenv install --dev black`.
I also setup my `Python: Select Interpreter` and pointed to my environment.

This is my Pipfile:

```ini
[dev-packages]
black = ">=24.2.0"
faker = ">=23.0.0"
pylint = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.11"
```

This is my `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.black]
color = true
diff = true
verbose = true
line-length = 88
target-version = ['py311']
include = '.lib/etl/.*/*.py'
required-version = "24.2.0"
```

I tried both with an environment (Pipenv) `black = ">=24.2.0"` and installing in my system `brew install black-sat/black/black-sat` and get the same results.

Versions:

- VSCode: 1.86.2
- System: MacOS Apple M1 Pro
- black: `24.2.0`

**Problem**

When I select my formatter and format the code I get the following result:

Before:

```py
def handler(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return add(a, b)




def add(a, b):
    """Add two numbers"""
    return a + b
```

After:

```py
[1m--- STDIN    2024-02-27 09:36:46.352177+00:00[0m
[1m+++ STDOUT   2024-02-27 09:36:46.355218+00:00[0m
[36m@@ -1,9 +1,7 @@[0m
 def handler(a: int, b: int) -> int:
     return add(a, b)
[31m-[0m
[31m-[0m
 
 
 def add(a, b):
     """Add two numbers"""
     return a + b
```

**Running from CLI**

If running `pipenv run black .` it correctly detects my `pyproject.toml` with the `black` args

```bash
❯ pipenv run black .                
Identified `/<project-path>/<project>` as project root containing a .git directory.
Using configuration from project root.
color: True
diff: True
verbose: True
line_length: 88
target_version: ['py311']
include: .lib/etl/.*/*.py
required_version: 24.2.0
...
@@ -11,14 +11,7 @@
 
     return add(a, b)
 
 
 def add(a, b):
-
-
-
-
-
-
-    
     """Add two numbers"""
     return a + b
would reformat /<path-to-file>/index.py
```

Comment: How do you perform formatting actions? What is your intended effect? Why don't you paste the sample code in the question? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I format the code using black (which is written in my question). My intended effect is to format the code (which is kind of obvious). Everything is written above. I am well aware of how to ask questions here thanks.

Comment: How do you format the code? What buttons or what way do you use? The same code doesn't really work for me, do you have any other extensions installed?Also, if you know how to ask questions, you won't have people commenting on needing other information.

Answer (score 0):

I have follow this and black formatter installed with success. I don't know if this help you, but this is what i did.

Change these vs-code prefs (File>Preferences>Settings):
(If there is no reference go to step 3)

```
"[python]": {
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
   "editor.formatOnSave": true,
   "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
   "editor.formatOnType": true,
   "python.formatting.provider": "black",
   "python.formatting.blackPath": "black"
  }
```

2. Go to a random project python file and save it
   3  If an pop up occured "Formatter black is not installed". Click yes and installed in the env of the project.
3. If you come from step 1 do pip install black and go from the beginning
4. You good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have the config (ex. above). So, I added your suggestions. In `blackPath` I tried from env (`which black`) and also just `black`. Both give me the same error